# How can I call a lua function in a c code function

Tags: c, lua

I have a lua table where I read it using a c code function

**test.lua**

```
tbl = {
    magna = {
        enable = true
        timer = 60
        Server = function()
            local Event_Type = { EV_MON, EV_RAIN, EV_SUN }
            local random_index = math.random(1, #Event_Type)
            local selected_event = Event_Type[random_index]
            SelectEvent(selected_event)
        end
    },
    power = {
        enable = true
        timer = 40
        Server = function()
            StartEffectID(55)
            EnableVisual(1150)
        end
    
    }
    
}

function main()
 for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
    read_table(k, v.enable, v.timer, v.Server)
 end
end
```

In the c code, according to the lua index, I define the structure entries

**C code**

```
struct my_test {
    int id;
    bool enable;
    int timer;
}

int enter_server(struct server *sv) {

    if(sv->login) {
        
    }
   return 1;
}

int read_table(lua_State *L) {  
    const char *name = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    
    if(check_config(name) == 0)
        return 0;
    
    struct my_test *tst = (struct my_test*) malloc(sizeof(struct my_test));

    tst->id = get_name_to_id(name);
    tst->enable = lua_toboolean(L , 2);
    tst->timer = (int)lua_tointeger(L, 3);
    
    if (lua_isfunction(L, 4)) {
        lua_pushvalue(L, 4);
        lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    
    lua_register(L, "read_table", read_table);
    
    if (luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua"))
        return;
        
    lua_getglobal(L, "main");
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Now I seek to do the following

How can I get the Lua `Server` function and set it to some variable in c to be able to call it in the `enter_server` function in c code

I want the `Server` function to run every time the `enter_server` function is called in other parts of c code

Comment: What's that `struct server` that you pass to `enter_server`? You obviously need some way on associate that server with the one passed to `read_table`. Once you figure it out (that's up to you and what you're trying to achieve; we cannot help you with that), you can use lua global registry and light user-data to store the `Server` lua function and then retrieve and call it later.